# How to change filename in a loop without having trouble with exclamation marks?

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%j in ("*") do (
    set filename=%%~nj
    set filename="!filename:(1)=!"
    if not "!filename!" == "%%~xj" ren "%%j" "!filename!%%~xj"
)
```

The problem with the script is I will get a syntax error if a file has `!` in its `filename`. What can I replace `!filename!` with to avoid this error?

Comment: You should check out [JREN.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6081) - a regular expression file renaming utility. The solution could then be as simple as `call jren "\(1\)" ""`

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to toggle delayed expansion, so that the `for` variables are expanded when it is disabled -- like this:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
for %%j in ("*") do (
    set "file=%%~j"
    set "filename=%%~nj"
    set "fileext=%%~xj"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "filename=!filename:(1)=!"
    if not "!filename!"=="!fileext!" (
        ren "!file!" "!filename!!fileext!"
    )
    endlocal
)
```

Besides that, I corrected the quotation. Note that I did not further check the logic of your script.

Answer (score 0):

Do the task *keeping delayed expansion **disabled***. Furthermore, following *commented* `.bat` script respects the facts that

- [`rename` command](http://ss64.com/nt/ren.html) would fail if target file already exists (otherwise, an error `A duplicate file name exists, or the file cannot be found` is raised), and
- currently running `.bat`/`.cmd` script can't be renamed/deleted.

The script correctly handles all [`cmd`/`.bat` *special* characters](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) if [valid in file names](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx) like `^` caret, `%` percent sign etc.:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "filemask=*"                 original file mask 

    rem prepare background for debugging and demonstration
pushd "D:\bat\Unusual Names"
set "filemask=0*!*.txt"          narrowed file mask

for %%j in ("%filemask%") do (
    if /I "%%~fj"=="%~f0" (
        rem do not rename currently running script "%~f0"
        rem applicable if %filemask% does not exclude %~x0 extension i.e. .bat/.cmd
        rem       e.g. if "%filemask%"=="*"
    ) else (
        set "file=%%~j"          name and extension
        set "filename=%%~nj"     name               only
        set "fileext=%%~xj"               extension only
        call :renFile
    )
)
popd
ENDLOCAL
goto :eof

:renFile
set "filename=%filename:(1)=%"
if not "%filename%%fileext%"=="%file%" (
    if exist "%filename%%fileext%" (
            rem renaming is not possible as target file already exists
        echo ??? "%file%"
    ) else (
            rem rename command is ECHOed merely for debugging and demonstration
            rem make it operational no sooner than debugged
        ECHO ren "%file%" "%filename%%fileext%"
    )
) else (
        rem output for debugging and demonstration
    echo NER "%filename%%fileext%"
)
goto :eof
```

**Sample output**:

```
==> dir /B "D:\bat\Unusual Names\0*!*.txt"
01exclam!ation(1).txt
02exc!lam!ation.txt
03exclam!ation!OS!(1).txt
04exc!lam!ation!OS!%OS%(1).txt
04exc!lam!ation!OS!%OS%.txt

==> D:\bat\SO\41714127.bat
ren "01exclam!ation(1).txt" "01exclam!ation.txt"
NER "02exc!lam!ation.txt"
ren "03exclam!ation!OS!(1).txt" "03exclam!ation!OS!.txt"
??? "04exc!lam!ation!OS!%OS%(1).txt"
NER "04exc!lam!ation!OS!%OS%.txt"

==>
```